# Unable to access AWS EC2 instance via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I accidentally changed publickey's file permissions, and now I'm unable to access via ssh using my key pair. Is there any way to restore this file's permissions?

Comment: Did you change the permissions on the EC2 instance's public key, or your local version ?

Comment: instance's! thats why I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can find solution in answer to question "Change key pair for ec2 instance": https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776183/179111