# Cannot ssh into ec2 instance created from snapshot

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, putty

Scenario:

- I have a running ec2 instance but don't have the key pair for the instance.
- I have a ftp-user account set up but don't have root access.
- **I want to duplicate the running instance to a new instance go gain root access.**

Problem:

- When I try to create a new instance, from a snapshot of the old one, putty says "Server refused our key" when trying to ssh into it...

This is what I did:

1. Created a snapshot of the old instance's ebs volume
2. From the snapshot I created an image

   - Made sure the architecture and kernel-id matched the old instance
3. I launched a new instance from the image

   - Created a new key pair
   - Created a new security group and made sure port 22 was open
4. Assigned an elastic ip to the instance
5. I downloaded and converted the key pair .pem file with puTTYgen

   - Loaded .pem file into puTTYgen
   - Used SSH-2 RSA 1024
   - Saved private key
6. Tried to ssh into the instance with putty (BUT FAILING)

   - Used elastic ip address
   - Tried with usernames: "ec2-user", "root", "ubuntu", "bitnami"

What could be wrong?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance/11776183#11776183

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image and your new instance still use the original keypair. Unless you prepare the instance to accept a new key at launch, it will not.

What you need to do is attach the volume to a new instance entirely, (created from a public ami). Mount the volume and edit the user's `authorized_keys` file on that volume. Put in your new key, and then move it back to the original instance.

Comment: thanks, step-by-step description of your above answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance/11776183#11776183