# Suddenly can't login to filezilla with EC2 amazon server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a free EC2 Amazon Ubuntu server and I was connected with putty and filezilla and I was transferring files. Suddenly I lost connection and now whenever I login on either putty of filezilla I get and error saying

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Any ideas what could be possibly happening? I think that before this happened I change the permissions of a folder. Don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: You used password or key to login?

Comment: @helloV key, there is no password

Answer (score 1):

> I think that before this happened I change the permissions of a
>   folder. Don't know if that's relevant

Did you change the permission of ~/.ssh directory? `ssh` expects the directory to have `700` as permission and the `~/.ssh/authorized_key` file to have `600` permission. Do you remember what exactly you changed?

You are out of luck if you changed the permissions of `~/.ssh` folder. There are other convoluted ways to restore access. You have to stop the instance, attach the root partition to another instance, then change the folder permission, detach the partition, attach it back to your original instance and start it. Search [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance) for answers.

Comment: Even if I did, how would I even change it back since I can't even access my server anymore.