# AWS Volume backup empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS.

I have a instance running in AWS. Now I want to get that instance volume into new instance. This volume contains things around 8GB.

I followed the 1st answer in the following post,[Change key pair for ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance)

After the step 5 (mounting the volume), I got a directory `lost+found` in /mnt/tmp folder.

But, inside the folder there is no folders or files.

What I am missing here.

Comment: Follow ---> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: Is it definitely an instance volume? I don't believe you can attach instance volumes to other instances, only EBS volumes. If it is an EBS volume, make sure you got the right one!

Comment: I have detached and attach in ELASTIC BLOCK STORE only.