# EC2 AWS system reachability failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, instance

The instance of my server was stopped by AWS; my instance is inaccessible now for a day.
How can I get a copy of my instance that was already stopped?

aws recommendation says terminate the instance and launch a replacement? If I terminate the instance, would I keep my data?

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Did you try taking an image of the EC2? And then create another ec2 instance and assign the cloned image to it?

Comment: Since most user load EC2 into EBS block, it is an emprical instance. So if you "Terminate" the instance, it will delete the instance including the data. Unless you mount the data and store it inside separate EBS block. The best way to get the data is to "STOP" the instance, make a copy of the snapshot and try to access the instance data using the non-destructive procedure as told here:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance/11776183#11776183

Comment: I am using a docker compose in which I install mysql. everything work inside of my componant. I wanna extract my database. is it possible knowing that i have no acces to my server. 
I have a copy of the source code and important files. But i did not I did not make a backup of the database.

Comment: problem solved.
Ty